# Change of Independent Variable in 2nd Order, Linear, Homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question:

Consider the ODE for y(x):

$x^2 y'' - x y' + (36x^{-4})y = 0$

Under the change of variable $t=x^{-2}$, this ODE becomes

$t^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} + At \frac{dy}{dt} + (B+Ct^2)y=0$

Find the values of $A,B,C$.

---

So it's the last term $(B+Ct^2)y$ that I can't seem to get right, there must be something I have to do with $y$ like I do with the derivatives but I don't know what? (I've never done this before). So, this is what I have:

$\begin{align}
x^2 y'' - x y' + (36x^{-4})y &= 0 \\[2ex]
\implies y'' - x^{-1}y' + 36x^{-6}y &= 0 \\[2ex]
\text{Now, for } t &= x^{-2} \text{ we have} \\[2ex]
\frac{dy}{dx} &= -2x^{-3} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} = -2t^{-3/2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} \\[2ex]
\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} &= 4x^{-6} \cdot \frac{d^2 y}{d t^2} + 6x^{-4} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} = 4t^{3} \cdot \frac{d^2 y}{d t^2} + 6t^{2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} 
\end{align}$

And so we substitute these into the original ODE, and we get

\begin{equation}
t^{-1}\left[4t^{3} \cdot \frac{d^2 y}{d t^2} + 6t^{2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}\right] - t^{-1/2}\left[-2t^{-3/2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}\right] + 36t^2y=0 \\[4ex]
\implies t^2y'' + 2ty' + 9t^2y=0
\end{equation}
Where the derivatives are now with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, the $B$ is simply zero. If you are unsure about changing variables you can always use another name for the "new" function which usually makes things a bit easier to understand.
$$
y(x)=\tilde{y}(t(x))\\
t(x)=x^{-2}
$$